# Creating XFCE4 Application Shortcuts from the terminal (CentOS)

Tags: centos, command-line, terminal, xfce

I am trying to add a new application shortcut in the command line which will load the terminal when you press `Ctrl + Alt + T`.

I am using the `xfconf-query` utility to monitor `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts` and the output I get when setting my shortcut via the Keyboard GUI is: `/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>t`.

[image: XFCE4 Keyboard settings]

I've been able to set other settings from the command line, for example changing the theme using the following command:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s "Adwaita"
```

However, I am not sure how to apply this a similar logic to my application shortcut, I just keep getting errors. Would anyone happen to have any ideas?

I tried the following command:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p '/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>t' -s xfce4-terminal
```

but I got the follow error message:

```
Property "/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>t" does not exist on channel "xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts". If a new property should be created, use the --create option.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property doesn't exist, it's necessary to create it using the `--create` option (or the synonymous `-n`) as indicated in the error. The following worked for me...

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -n -t 'string' -p '/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>t' -s xfce4-terminal
```

Note that it was also necessary to add the type of the value, although 'String' as found for a type in the Xfce Settings Editor wouldn't work; it had to be 'string'.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem. Despite there already being a shortcut entry assigned to xfce4-terminal a whole new entry needs to be made to accommodate the shortcut I want to use to load the terminal.